# How to add double quotes to elements inside a array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am very new to the Ruby, I have array and I want to add double quotes to all alpha-numeric elements

array I have:  `a = [a255b78, wr356672]`

Array i required:  `a =["a255b78", "wr356672"]`

Is there any direct way to do this?

Comment: is `a` a string in your first example? otherwise, it's not valid ruby

Comment: Yes, It is a string.

Comment: Please, do not use Ruby on Rails 3. It has not been maintained in a long time and has unpatched security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Presumably, as you indicate in a comment, `a = "[a255b78, wr356672]"`. Please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the "[]" and split on `", "`:

```
str = "[a255b78, wr356672]"
p arr = str[1..-2].split(", ") # => ["a255b78", "wr356672"]
```

This does NOT add double quotes to all alpha-numeric elements; it converts a String to an Array of Strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "[a255b78, wr356672]"
```

```
str.scan(/\w+/)
  #=> ["a255b78", "wr356672"]
```

See [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan). The regular expression matches one or more word characters. Word characters (matching `\w`) are letters, digits and the underscore.